# Abort following statement from SQLite Triggers

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I want to create a [SQLite trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) similar to this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "prevent_duplicate_emails"
BEFORE INSERT OF "email" ON "users"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT("email") FROM "users" WHERE "email" LIKE NEW."email"

    # FIX ME!
    IF COUNT("email") > 0:
        RAISE ABORT|FAIL, NEW."email" || ' already exists'
    ELSE:
        INSERT INTO "unique_emails" VALUES (NEW."email");
    ENDIF;
END;
```

So basically when I do:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("email") VALUES ("adam@eden.com"); # WORKS
INSERT INTO "users" ("email") VALUES ("adam@eden.com"); # FAILS
INSERT INTO "users" ("email") VALUES ("eve@eden.com"); # WORKS
```

The first `INSERT` will originate two new records (in tables `users` and `unique_emails`), while the second `INSERT` will fail and originate no records at all. Is it possible to do this from a trigger?

I read the docs, but besides not fully understanding `RAISE` I don't see a way to achieve this.

**PS**: I know I could take several other approaches in order to get a list of unique emails, but that's not the point of this question. It would really simplify things if I could do this check / abort from within the trigger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create trigger for sqlite database that prevents insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983495/create-trigger-for-sqlite-database-that-prevents-insert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985827/89771) the answer:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS "prevent_duplicate_emails"
BEFORE INSERT OF "email" ON "users"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Email already exists.')
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "unique_emails"
                  WHERE "email" LIKE NEW."email");
    INSERT INTO "unique_emails" VALUES (NEW."email");
END;
```